# Testing batch apex

Tags: unit-test, batch

Help me in writingTest class for Batch apex

I created Batch apex to send emails to owners of the lead based on certain conditions.
I have to write a test class to test gov limits.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any specific problems you are encountering?

Comment: I haven't write anything.Give me an idea to test.I'm new to batch apex.Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please help me testing following batch apex.Thanks](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8118/please-help-me-testing-following-batch-apex-thanks)

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to write a post. Pay particular attention to the section on "What not to ask" please. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read this documentation from Salesforce.com related to Batch Apex. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm

There is an example for testing batch apex in that page which can help you.